# Getting a path for each component in NSIS

Tags: windows, nsis

I'm trying to create an installer with NSIS that installs 3 different components to three different paths. I want the users to select/confirm each of them, but they should only be asked if they've selected the relevant component.

Since pages can't appear in sections, I'm at a loss how to do this

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple directory pages:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

InstallDir $ProgramFiles32\Foo\Bar

Var Comp1Path
Var Comp2Path

Page Components
PageEx Directory
    DirText "Blah blah 1"
    DirVar $Comp1Path
    PageCallbacks Comp1Pre
PageExEnd
PageEx Directory
    DirText "Blah blah 2"
    DirVar $Comp2Path
    PageCallbacks Comp2Pre
PageExEnd
Page InstFiles

Section /o Comp1 SID_C1
DetailPrint "Installing Comp1 to $Comp1Path"
SectionEnd

Section Comp2 SID_C2
DetailPrint "Installing Comp2 to $Comp2Path"
SectionEnd

Function Comp1Pre
StrCpy $Comp1Path $InstDir\Comp1
${IfNot} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_C1}
    Abort ; Skipping this page
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function Comp2Pre
StrCpy $Comp2Path $InstDir\Comp2
${IfNot} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_C2}
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

; In this example the next button on the components page might be the last page before InstFiles so we have to update the button text
!include WinMessages.nsh
Function .onSelChange
GetDlgItem $1 $hwndParent 1
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_C1}
${OrIf} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_C2}
    SendMessage $1 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(^NextBtn)"
${Else}
    SendMessage $1 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(^InstallBtn)"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Another alternative would be to create a custom page with nsDialogs and just disable or hide the text fields the user does not need to confirm...

Comment: Variables are empty by default, just setting them to something here so the next button is not grayed out. You probably want to specify so sort of default path for these. You can also do that in .onInit etc.

Comment: Oops! Deleted my question just after you answered it :-)

Comment: Thanks again! This really got me started & now, 7 hours later, I have a working installer :-)